# Converting HTML to Word in PHP and facing performance issue when there are images

Tags: php, html, performance, ms-word

I am converting HTML to Word in PHP. When I include some images like below:

```
$dowIcon = "http://caremerge.loc/hfp-web/assets/images/activity_default_user.png";
            $this->template .= "<SPAN class='key'>" . "<IMG width='15' height='15' src='". $dowIcon ."'/>" . "&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $this->dimensions[$i]['dimension']['v_name'] . "</SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

and download the Word file on the client side, it takes 5-10 minutes to open depending upon the number of images.

How can I increase its performance, or alternatively something like, Word opens and images take time to load, but the user has the document open with the text already available?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to load the Word document progressively. You will need to reduce the size of your images so that they open up faster.

Plus, it's not really a proper way to create a Word document.

Try this framework instead and use the RTF format: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: But, images are already small in sizes, sometimes same image repeat like 10-15 times can I do something like reuse the images that are loaded already?

Comment: And, I have to stick with current formate very strictly "https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord" this lib will not allow me i guess and will not give same result as it from html to pdf, what says ?